# Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets' with Live Server enabled

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I get this error when try to run project in VSCode with Live Server Enabled

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets'.
> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file 'C:\Users\*\build\app\intermediates\assets\debug\mergeDebugAssets'
```

in project I try to get json from `apis` folder

`await _getJson('http://127.0.0.1:5500/apis/persons.json')`

I tried to `flutter clean & flutter pub get` but it doesn't help.

How to fix it or is there an alternative for Live Server?